# How to disable beep in bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, imagemagick

When I take a screenshot of my browser, console makes a "beep" sound. The problem is that my script has a loop with sleep 0.1. Is there a way to turn off "beep" sound?

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
   import -window "Welcome - Mozilla Firefox" screen.png
   convert screen.png -crop 713x50+5+900 output.png
   ....
   sleep 0.1
done
```

Comment: [Option `--silent`](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot/issues/9)?

Comment: It's not bash making the beep sound, it's your `import` command; it would still beep if it were called from Python or Java or any other language instead. The question needs to be about `import` (or the package it's from), not the shell. (The only case where the shell could do anything about it is if it's doing that by emitting an appropriate sequence to the terminal, but again, someone would need to know more about `import` to know if that's the case; expertise in bash doesn't help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the fine documentation at imagemagick.org, `import` has a [`-silent`](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#silent) option for suppressing the beep.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setterm -blength 0` ? 
It works for sure when you hit tab wrongly, and it may work for you